# Heading moves other menu items and aligns texts of them to its bottom

Tags: html, css

Ok, I didn't really know how to describe title, but I find this a very strange. I have a very simple navbar looking like this :

```css
     html,body{
      width:100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      background: #EEE;
     }
  .navbar-menu{
   display:block;
   color:white;
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   background: black;
  }

  .top-navbar{
   padding: 0;
   margin:0;
   width:100%;
  }
  .navbar-menu-item{
   height:50px;
   font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
   display:inline-block;
   background: red;
   margin:0;
   margin-right:5px;
  }
  .navbar-menu-item > *{
       display: inline;
     }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='top-navbar'>
     <div class="navbar-menu">
   <div class="navbar-md "> <!--hidden-xs hidden-sm -->
    <div class="navbar-menu-item">
     <span>Profile</span>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-menu-item">
     <h2>Profile</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-menu-item">
     <span>Profile</span>
       </div>
    <div class="navbar-menu-item">
     Profile
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-menu-item">
     Profile
    </div>
   </div>
          <!--For now
   <div class="navbar-xs hidden-md hidden-lg">
       SOmething..
   </div>
          -->
  </div>
 </div>
```

Now when you run the snippet you see how all texts are bottom aligned and this moves menu items down, but they don't have margin, so it's not the cause, I don't know why is this happening since `h2` element is child of `.navbar-menu-item` and I don't know how it's effecting other menu items. I tried searching on the google with no luck. If you are willing to answer, please include why this is happening :)

Comment: `.navbar-menu-item > * { vertical-align: top; }`

Comment: right @CBroe :) could you post it as an answer ?

Comment: or set all children to `height: 100%;` I think that looks better, what ever you need

Comment: @ScottSelby that wouldn't work :) if you meant `.navbar-menu-item > * { height:100%; }`

Comment: If @CBroe answers please mark his as correct, not mine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CBroe mentioned, his solutions is correct. Add `.navbar-menu-item > * { vertical-align: top; }`

```css
     html,body{
      width:100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      background: #EEE;
     }
  .navbar-menu{
   display:block;
   color:white;
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   background: black;
  }

  .top-navbar{
   padding: 0;
   margin:0;
   width:100%;
  }
  .navbar-menu-item{
   height:50px;
   font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
   display:inline-block;
   background: red;
   margin:0;
   margin-right:5px;
            vertical-align: top;
  }
  .navbar-menu-item > *{
       display: inline;
     }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='top-navbar'>
     <div class="navbar-menu">
   <div class="navbar-md "> <!--hidden-xs hidden-sm -->
    <div class="navbar-menu-item">
     <span>Profile</span>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-menu-item">
     <h2>Profile</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-menu-item">
     <span>Profile</span>
       </div>
    <div class="navbar-menu-item">
     Profile
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-menu-item">
     Profile
    </div>
   </div>
          <!--For now
   <div class="navbar-xs hidden-md hidden-lg">
       SOmething..
   </div>
          -->
  </div>
 </div>
```